# 2 module build trigger by scm polling of both repo

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have Jenkins build which have 2 modules. I use trigger build by SCM polling option. My SCM is Subversion. I see that only changes in first module trigger build. Changes in second module does not trigger build. I want to setup my project in way when changes in both modules will trigger my build.

How can I do such setup?

At the moment I use another task to monitor code changes in second module and trigger my build.

Comment: Check the pull log.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I have 2 different modules I use in my build. Both modules are in their own repos. If I check repo log for one module I see all commits, when I check repo log for another module I see all its commits. I want to rebuild project if code base has changed in one or another repo. But now in Jenkins build setup I see only one SCM polling option and it works only for first module. I ask if it possible to setup build to SCM poll both's module repos (e.g. workaround or some plugin)

Comment: Open your job and click on the left side on svn polling log.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. I found I mixed 2 problems. 1) For project with real 2 modules I see success polling log and there are no changes in second module. 2) For project which have external dependency (second module in my initial question) which is checked out by providing additional credentials in subversion setup section and which have such changes I see `E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials` error in polling log. So, will look forward for this error message and will try to commit something to verify second module changes polling from step 1 !